# matplotlib contour plot: getting spurious lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have the following code to plot the following 2D function:

```
$$ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x*y+1} = 4 $$
```

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xlist = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 100) # Create 1-D arrays for x,y dimensions
ylist = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 100) 
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist) # Create 2-D grid xlist,ylist values
F = (X**2 + Y**2)/(X*Y+1) 
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, F, [4.0],linewidths=0.5, colors='k')

ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', axis='both')
```

I get a spurious lines.

[image]

Any help regarding the issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the relatively coarse resolution of the image your analyzing.

If I crank the number of points in your calls to `linspace`, I get a better looking plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 8))
for n, ax in zip([50, 100, 500, 1000], axes.flat):
    xlist = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, n) # Create 1-D arrays for x,y dimensions
    ylist = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, n) 
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist) # Create 2-D grid xlist,ylist values
    F = (X**2 + Y**2)/(X*Y+1) 
    CS = ax.contour(X, Y, F, [4.0],linewidths=0.5, colors='k')

    ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
    ax.grid(b=True, which='major', axis='both') 
    ax.set_title(f"N ={n}")
```

[image]

Comment: I was not talking about the smoothness of the contours. There should not be 4 contours should there ? Because the equation is that of hyperbola. Why I am not getting one hyperbola. Why do I get two ?

Comment: plugging in some x & y values myself, these plots look right to me. If you hold `x` and `F` constant, you get end up with a quadratic equation with 2 possible solutions

Comment: yes that is what I am saying. Say x=0, F=4. y should have two solutions +2 and -2  Which results in the inner hyperbolas (i.e. the ones close to the origin). Why are we getting the outer hyperbolas ? It implies 4 solutions ?

Comment: You're plotting a surface. Each "side" of that surface hits F=4 twice in its way up to positive infinitity and back to down to negative infinity

Comment: I tried the same in Wolfarm alpha using the command:  contour plot (x^2+y^2)/(x*y+1) = 4 from x = -10 to 10, y = -10 to 10. Gives just a hyperbola.